# Replace only exact string

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to replace exact string only in a csv file using another csv as dictionary.
This is my code

```
import re
text = open("input.csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
replacelist = open("replace.csv","r", encoding="ISO-8859-1").readlines()
for r in replacelist:
    r = r.split(",")
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace(r[0],r[1])
print ({r[0]})
print ({r[1]})
x = open("new.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

Is it possible to use replace method to only replace exact match strings? Should I import and use re.sub() instead of replace?

input.csv example

```
ciao123;xxxxx;0
ciao12345;xxzzx;2
```

replace.csv example

```
ciao123,ok
aaaa,no
bbb,cc
```

Only first line in input.csv should be replaced.

Comment: you mean, replace `ciao123;xxxxx;0` with `ok;xxxxx;0` ?

Comment: yes, correct right

Comment: there could be more than one occurrence of `ciao123` in table, how to you plan to handle it? - replace all occurance?

Comment: yes, if there is one than more occurrence, replace all but only when it's an exact match of full string (ciao12345 should not be replaced and become ok45)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per your comments, your task would be much simpler and you don't need to play with regex as well!

Basically, you are trying to replace something in a csv column if it is a exact word match, if that is the case, you should not be treating it as raw text, treat it as a column data.

If you do so, you could use one example like below:

```py
text = open("input.csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1").readlines()
replacelist = open("replace.csv","r", encoding="ISO-8859-1").readlines()

# make a replace word dictionary with O(n) time complexity
replace_data = {i.split(',')[0]: i.split(',')[1] for i in replacelist}

# Now treat data in input.csv as tabular data to replace the words
# Start another loop of O(n) time complexity
for idx, line in enumerate(text):
    line_lis = line.split(';')
    if line_lis[0] in replace_data:
       only replace word if it is meant to be replaced
       line_lis[0] = replace_data.get(line_lis[0])
       text[idx] = ';'.join(line_lis)

# write results
with open("new.csv","w") as f:
    f.writelines(text)
```

Result would be as:

```
ok;xxxxx;0
ciao12345;xxzzx;2
```